# Split a string every n words into smaller Strings

Tags: python, string, split

Situation: I have a chunk of text that I want to break down into smaller strings. After every n Words.

```
text = "This is a small example Text, showcasing my desired output."
```

Should be split with `n = 4` into:

```
textList = ['This is a small', 'example Text, showcasing my', 'desired output.']
```

My idea is to split it in a list with only single words using:

```
n = len(text)    
textList = text.split(' ', n)
```

And then use `join()` to put it together but I'm stuck because:

```
for x in range(0, 3):
    ' '.join(textList)
```

is not putting the list to my desired output together

Comment: Try [`re.findall(r'\W*(?:\w+\W+){1,4}', text)`](https://ideone.com/GYIJvA).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
text = 'This is a small example Text, showcasing my desired output.'
text = text.split()
n = 4
[' '.join(text[i:i+n]) for i in range(0,len(text),n)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
text = "This is a small example Text, showcasing my desired output."

def split_sentence(texto):
    split_texto = texto.split()
    comb_st = [] # Combinaciones split
    i = 0
    for st in split_texto:
        comb_st.append(st)
        if split_texto == split_texto[-1]:
            break
        else:
            add_st = ""
            for cs2 in split_texto[i + 1: ]:
                add_st += " " + cs2
                add_st = add_st.lstrip()
                comb_st.append(st + " " + add_st)
        i += 1
    # for i in range(len(comb_st)):
    #     comb_st[i] = comb_st[i].split()
    return comb_st

comb_split_texto = split_sentence(text)

OUTPUT:
This
This is
This is a
This is a small
This is a small example
This is a small example Text,
This is a small example Text, showcasing
This is a small example Text, showcasing my
This is a small example Text, showcasing my desired
This is a small example Text, showcasing my desired output.
is
is a
is a small
is a small example
is a small example Text,
is a small example Text, showcasing
is a small example Text, showcasing my
is a small example Text, showcasing my desired
is a small example Text, showcasing my desired output.
a
a small
a small example
a small example Text,
a small example Text, showcasing
a small example Text, showcasing my
a small example Text, showcasing my desired
a small example Text, showcasing my desired output.
small
small example
small example Text,
small example Text, showcasing
small example Text, showcasing my
small example Text, showcasing my desired
small example Text, showcasing my desired output.
example
example Text,
example Text, showcasing
example Text, showcasing my
example Text, showcasing my desired
example Text, showcasing my desired output.
Text,
Text, showcasing
Text, showcasing my
Text, showcasing my desired
Text, showcasing my desired output.
showcasing
showcasing my
showcasing my desired
showcasing my desired output.
my
my desired
my desired output.
desired
desired output.
output.
```