# text segmentation by the number of words in python

Tags: python-3.x

can anyone tell me what is the problem with my own code?
I want to segment a big text into small texts by words. for example, each segment contains 60 words each.

```
file=r'C:\Users\Nujou\Desktop\Master\thesis\steganalysis\dataset\economy2.txt'

openFile= open(file, 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig')
words= openFile.read().split()
#print (words)

i = 0
for idx, w in enumerate(words, start=0):
    textNum = 1
    while textNum <= 20:
        wordAsText = []
        print("word list before:", wordAsText)
        while i<idx+60:
            wordAsText.append(words[i])
            i+=1
        print ("word list after:", wordAsText)
        textSeg=' '.join(wordAsText)
        print (textNum, textSeg)
        files = open(r"C:\Users\Nujou\Desktop\Master\thesis\steganalysis\dataset\datasetEco\Eco" + str(textNum) + ".txt", "w", encoding='utf-8-sig')
        files.write(textSeg)
        files.close()
        idx+=60
        if textNum!=20:
            continue
        textNum+=1
```

my big file (economy2) contains more than 12K words.

EDIT:
thanks for all responses. I tried what I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40425033/python-split-string-every-n-word-in-smaller-strings) and it is achieved my require.

Edited Code:

```
file=r'C:\Users\Nujou\Desktop\Master\thesis\steganalysis\dataset\economy2.txt'

openFile= open(file, 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig')
words= openFile.read().split()
#print (words)
n=60
segments=[' '.join(words[i:i+n]) for i in range(0,len(words),n)] #from link
i=1
for s in segments:
    seg = open(r"C:\Users\Nujou\Desktop\Master\thesis\steganalysis\dataset\datasetEco\Eco" + str(i) + ".txt", "w", encoding='utf-8-sig')
    seg.write(s)
    seg.close()
    i+=1
```

Comment: What *is* the problem? How does this not work as expected?

Comment: it gives this error "IndexError: list index out of range", and did not write the segmented files. I want just 20 small files with 60 words each not whole the big file.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code with your debugger? Find out where you're indexing a list incorrectly?

Comment: "IndexError: list index out of range"
You never increase textNum before comparing it to 20, you might just have an endless loop in there